# What is the largest query a MYSQL Command can upload to the database?

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to upload roughly 300KB to a Long Text and I keep getting the following error.
I'm uploading to my database using the MYSQL .NET connector.
I'm trying to upload a file from a 3ds model as text so it has alot of unrecognizable ASCII characters if that makes a difference.

This is my upload function:

```
public void Upload(string queue)
        {
            MySqlCon.Open();
            MySqlCommand command = MySqlCon.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = queue;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MySqlCon.Close();


        }
```

And this is what im calling:

```
string FBXQuery = "UPDATE 'itemmodel' SET 'modelFile'='" + FBX + "'
 WHERE 'modelName'='" + txt_Name.Text + "'; ";
             SQL.Upload(FBXQuery);
```

Here is the error:

```
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unhandled exception</Description><AppDomain>Item Manager.vshost.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException, MySql.Data, Version=6.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d</ExceptionType><Message>Fatal error encountered during command execution.</Message><StackTrace>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Item_Manager.MYSQL.Upload(String queue) in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Item Manager\Item Manager\MYSQL.cs:line 187
   at Item_Manager.NewItem.btn_Upload_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Item Manager\Item Manager\NewItem.cs:line 64
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message&amp;amp; m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG&amp;amp; msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
   at Item_Manager.Form1.newItemToolStripMenuItem_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Item Manager\Item Manager\Form1.cs:line 81
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message&amp;amp; m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG&amp;amp; msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at Item_Manager.Program.Main() in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Item Manager\Item Manager\Program.cs:line 18
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()</StackTrace><ExceptionString>MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Fatal error encountered during command execution. ---&amp;gt; MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Parameter '?' must be defined.
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.SerializeParameter(MySqlParameterCollection parameters, MySqlPacket packet, String parmName)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.InternalBindParameters(String sql, MySqlParameterCollection parameters, MySqlPacket packet)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.BindParameters()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.PreparableStatement.Execute()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Item_Manager.MYSQL.Upload(String queue) in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Item Manager\Item Manager\MYSQL.cs:line 187
   at Item_Manager.NewItem.btn_Upload_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Item Manager\Item Manager\NewItem.cs:line 64
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message&amp;amp; m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG&amp;amp; msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
   at Item_Manager.Form1.newItemToolStripMenuItem_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Item Manager\Item Manager\Form1.cs:line 81
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message&amp;amp; m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG&amp;amp; msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at Item_Manager.Program.Main() in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Item Manager\Item Manager\Program.cs:line 18
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()</ExceptionString><InnerException><ExceptionType>MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException, MySql.Data, Version=6.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d</ExceptionType><Message>Parameter '?' must be defined.</Message><StackTrace>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.SerializeParameter(MySqlParameterCollection parameters, MySqlPacket packet, String parmName)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.InternalBindParameters(String sql, MySqlParameterCollection parameters, MySqlPacket packet)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.BindParameters()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.PreparableStatement.Execute()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Parameter '?' must be defined.
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.SerializeParameter(MySqlParameterCollection parameters, MySqlPacket packet, String parmName)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.InternalBindParameters(String sql, MySqlParameterCollection parameters, MySqlPacket packet)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.BindParameters()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.PreparableStatement.Execute()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)</ExceptionString></InnerException></Exception></TraceRecord>
```

Comment: Looks like you have a parameter you didn't bind. Your exception says `Parameter '?' must be defined`.

Comment: I've posted an answer to your actual question, but if you look at your stack trace, you can see that the error you are getting is `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Parameter '?' must be defined.`

Comment: The largest allowed packet i can upload is 232M according to my config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that it is related to the `max_allowed_packet` configuration variable -- in theory, it can be up to 1GB, but is likely set much lower than that.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet

Comment: Going through my file it has a bunch of ' and "